# Bootstrap 3 carousel fixed aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I use Bootstrap 3.3 carousel and it works like a charm with same aspect ratio images. But when I use different images with different aspect ratio(for example 1600*700 and 1600*1200) height of carousel starts to change. That looks weird when sliding.

[image]

**Whats a best way to lock carousel aspect ratio (for example 16x9) and fit different images to it?**

I want get smth like this:

[image]

*For discussion convenience here is my currently carousel code example:*

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="motor1600*700.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="boat1600*1200.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right carousel controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this: [bootstrap carousel with fixed height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36326799/8254484)

Comment: @awran5 I saw this but there is fixed height of carousel. I need default responsive carousel and fixed aspect ratio both.